# Manichaeism almost becoming state religion of Roman Empire

Tags: religion, roman-empire

I am reading Yuval Noah Harari's *Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind*, an excellent source throughout.

At one point (on p. 270 in the German edition) the author mentions a turning point in history where Manichaeism, a dualistic religion whose founder lived in the 3rd century AD, could almost have become the Roman Empire's state religion.

What specific time or event may he be referring to?

Answer (score 2):

> Manichaeism rapidly spread west into the Roman Empire. From Egypt it moved across northern Africa (where the young Augustine temporarily became a convert) and reached Rome in the early 4th century. The 4th century marked the height of Manichaean expansion in the West, *[Manichaeism](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Manichaeism)*

Comment: I am interested in a specific time (year) or event.